# Клики по пунктам контекстного меню браузера

Tags: javascript

Как отследить, что юзер открыл ссылку через правая кн.мыши->"Открыть ссылку в новой вкладке" контекстного меню ? Я хочу выполнить функцию при клике на пункт "Открыть ссылку в новой вкладке"

Comment: Из контекста страницы - никак. Из контекста расширения - возможно и можно отследить, но вряд ли удастся подменить.

Comment: максимум можно попытаться отловить событие открытия _oncontextmenu_, Но это не даст доступа к нативному меню

Comment: можно попробовать пойти путем замены контекстного меню на свое

Comment: @VyacheslavDanshin, ябпосмотрел как Вы реализуете в кастомном меню его стандартные функции.

Comment: возможно не требуется реализовывать все контекстное меню )))